# Raspberry Pi 4: "omxplayer -o both" produces bad quality audio from jack but HDMI audio is fine

Tags: audio, hdmi, omxplayer, nginx

I'm using OMX Player to play a video stream sent to a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B (4GB) powered by a 20W / 3.0A Anker USB C plug. (Based on [this project](https://aaronparecki.com/2020/09/07/7/raspberry-pi-streaming-server).)

The code I'm using to launch OMX Player and route audio is as follows:

```
exec omxplayer -o both rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/$name;
```

This sends both the video and the audio to the HDMI display and additionally sends the audio to the headphone hack on the Pi as well, but the audio coming from the headphone jack is low quality, fuzzy and distorted. The HDMI audio is fine, however, and if I change the code to either...

```
exec omxplayer -o hdmi rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/$name;
```

... or ...

```
exec omxplayer -o local rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/$name;
```

I can get great quality audio from **either** the headphone jack **or** the HDMI port in isolation, but *not at the same time*.

So OMX Player and the Pi 4 are capable of outputting good quality audio from the headphone jack, but only if it's not *also* being outputted via HDMI.

I've also added the following line to **/boot/config.txt** but it made no difference:

```
audio_pwm_mode=2
```

I then wondered if it was a power issue on the Pi so I've tried with a OnePlus power supply capable of outputting up to 6.0A at 5V but no joy.

If anyone has any ideas of what else I could try, I'd be very grateful. Thanks in advance! :)